# Imap: Get multiple sections from email with one command

Tags: batch-file, curl, libcurl

I crossposted this in the [curl mailing list (curl-users)](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2019-03/0016.html).

I know how to get multiple parts of an email header like this:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE%20FROM%20TO%20SUBJECT)" -u "user:password"
```

But is it possible to get multiple sections (received date and text in 
my case) at once? I want to combine these two commands:

1: Fetch email receiving date

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE)" -u "user:password"
```

2: Fetch email text

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=TEXT" -u "user:password"
```

I tried something like this:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE);SECTION=TEXT" -u "user:password"
```

–––––––––––––––––––––

Thank you diciu, this works just fine. I have an additional question:

When i add `--ouput output.txt` the file only contains the last FETCH (`SECTION=TEXT` in this case). Is it possible to output all FETCH results to one output file? I know i can use `>> output.txt` to append but i use that to write a log file within the same command.

Here my full command:

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=295;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE)" "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=295;SECTION=TEXT"-u "user:password" --output output.txt --verbose >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the two requests one after another, e.g.

```
curl --url "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=HEADER.FIELDS%20(DATE)" "imaps://imap.ionos.de/INBOX;UID=216;SECTION=TEXT" -u "user:password"
```

*curl* will issue the two commands on the same session, that is after SELECT-ing the folder it will yield two FETCH commands.

Comment: Please see addition to original post.

Comment: You can't do that. Each request has it's own --output parameter so if you just say curl url1 --output out.txt url2 --output out.txt you end up overwriting the first result.